# How do I change backgrounds in sections? (not <div>, <section>)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website code's index.html, I have various sections that you can see when you click onto buttons. Here is the site: https://olddigibox.github.io/sky-web-epg/ (the only button you can click is MORE...)

I want the background image to change when you go onto the MORE... section page. How can I do this?
Here is the site repository: https://github.com/OldDigibox/sky-web-epg

I have tried changing the background using CSS and JS, but didn't work. Here is backgrounds.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    while (true) {
        if ($("guide").css("display") == "flex") {
            $("body").get(0).style.setProperty("background-image", "url('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/649968233553723405/709086018942402631/image1.jpg')");
        }
        else {
            $("body").get(0).style.setProperty("background-image", "url('img/tv_guide.png')");
        }
    }
});
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Zurich';
}

:root {
    font-size: 16px;
    --font-colour: white;
    --main-colour: rgb(0, 37, 201);
    --sub-colour: rgb(0, 26, 143);
    --listnum-colour: rgb(126, 126, 255);
    --main-colour-hover: #FCDA25;
    --sub-colour-hover: rgb(197, 197, 0);
    --listnum-colour-hover: rgb(0, 0, 179);
    --font-colour-hover: rgb(0, 0, 179);
    --background-image-blank: url('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/649968233553723405/709086018942402631/image1.jpg');
    --background-image: url("img/tv_guide.png");
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #111;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

main {
    background: var(--background-image);
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: center;
}

section.guide {
    background: url("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/649968233553723405/709086018942402631/image1.jpg");
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*#guide {
    background: var(--background-image-blank);
    background-position: top;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    justify-content: center;
}*/

.menulisting[id] {
    display: none;
}

.menulisting#main {
    display: flex;
}

.menulisting {
    width: 65%;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}

    .menulisting li {
        width: 100%;
        height: 31.5px;
        margin: 1px 0px;
        background: var(--main-colour);
        list-style-type: none;
        color: var(--font-colour);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }

        .menulisting li:nth-of-type(1) {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    .menulisting a {
        color: var(--font-colour);
    }

li .num {
    background: var(--sub-colour);
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 5px;
    color: var(--listnum-colour);
    text-align: center;
}

.menulisting li:hover {
    background: var(--main-colour-hover);
    color: var(--font-colour-hover);
}

    .menulisting li:hover .num {
        background: var(--sub-colour-hover);
        color: var(--listnum-colour-hover);
    }

    .menulisting li:hover a {
        color: var(--font-colour-hover);
    }

.menulisting li:focus {
    background: var(--main-colour-hover);
    color: var(--font-colour-hover);
}

    .menulisting li:focus .num {
        background: var(--sub-colour-hover);
        color: var(--listnum-colour-hover);
    }

    .menulisting li:focus a {
        color: var(--font-colour-hover);
    }

.links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: right;
    color: var(--main-colour);
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.guidelisting {
    width: 150%;
    height: 410px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}

.guidelisting li {
    font-family: 'ZurichTV';
}

.titles {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: left;
    color: var(--main-colour);
}
/* Font Families */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zurich';
    src: url('Zurich Bold Extended.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ZurichTV';
    src: url('Zurich Bold Condensed.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sky Guide</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <iframe allow="autoplay" style="display:none" id="player" type="audio/mpeg">
        </iframe>
        <!--Landing Page-->
        <section class="menulisting" id="main">
            <li onclick="toPage('main', 'guide')">
                <div class="num">1</div>
                ALL CHANNELS
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">2</div>
                ENTERTAINMENT
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">3</div>
                LIFESTYLE & CULTURE
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">4</div>
                MOVIES
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">5</div>
                SPORTS
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">6</div>
                NEWS
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">7</div>
                DOCUMENTARIES
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">8</div>
                KIDS
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">9</div>
                MUSIC
            </li>
            <li onclick="toPage('main', 'more')">
                <div class="num">0</div>
                MORE...
            </li>
            <div class="links">
                <a>Anytime</a>
                <a>Planner</a>
                <a>A-Z</a>
                <a>Favourites</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--More Page-->
        <section class="menulisting" id="more">
            <li>
                <div class="num">1</div>
                RADIO
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">2</div>
                SHOPPING
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">3</div>
                RELIGION
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">4</div>
                INTERNATIONAL
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">5</div>
                GAMING & DATING
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">6</div>
                SPECIALIST
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="num">7</div>
                ADULT
            </li>
            <li onclick="toPage('more', 'custom')">
                <div class="num">8</div>
                CUSTOM PAGES
            </li>
            <li onclick="toPage('more', 'main')">
                <div class="num">0</div>
                BACK UP
            </li>
            <div class="links">
                <a>Anytime</a>
                <a>Planner</a>
                <a>A-Z</a>
                <a>Favourites</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--More Page-->
        <section class="menulisting" id="custom">
            <li onclick="lightsOff()">
                <div class="num">1</div>
                LIGHT SWITCH
            </li>
            <li onclick="toPage('custom', 'more')">
                <div class="num">0</div>
                BACK UP
            </li>
            <div class="links">
                <a>Anytime</a>
                <a>Planner</a>
                <a>A-Z</a>
                <a>Favourites</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--Channel Guide-->
        <section class="menulisting" id="guide">
            <div class="titles">ALL CHANNELS</div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    101   BBC One
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    102   BBC Two
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    103   ITV
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    104   Channel 4
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    105   Channel 5
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    106   Sky One
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    107   Sky Witness
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    108   Sky Atlantic
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    109   W
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelisting">
                <li>
                    110   GOLD
                </li>
                <li>
                    A SHOW
                </li>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a style="background-color:yellow; color:black" onclick="toPage('guide', 'main')">BACK UP</a>
                <a>Anytime</a>
                <a>Planner</a>
                <a>A-Z</a>
                <a>Favourites</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <!--<audio id="player" allow="autoplay" autoplay>
    </audio>-->
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="epgsongs.js"></script>
<!--<script src="backgrounds.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop (`while(true){...}`) the browser will never update as you tie up the js thread preventing anything else to happen. Put the style changing code in a click event listener if you want it done on a button click

Comment: Also note `$('guide')` will only find elements named `guide`, ie `<guide></guide>`. did you mean to use a class or id selector, eg `$('.guide')` or `$('#guide')`

Comment: @patrick-evans Yes, I meant to use id selector since the section ID is guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you have that loop in your function. You can use jquery's toggleClass() on the click event or in your case, inside of toPage() if you create 2 classes with the background images you want. It's not your exact code, but close enough to get the idea.

```
.backgroundImg1 {
  background-image: url('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/649968233553723405/709086018942402631/image1.jpg');
}

.backgroundImg2 {
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/blue-abstract-background-or-texture-picture-id1138395421');
}


$('main').toggleClass('backgroundImg2')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvd6trnp/1/

EDIT:
If you want to change backgrounds for the other 'pages', you will have to add additional classes for the backgrounds you want and have a switch statement.

https://jsfiddle.net/krob636/tpvno64z/20/

That will get messy though, so it is probably best to wrap your sections in an element, apply the background images to that element, then show/hide it.

https://jsfiddle.net/krob636/Lqanfxmc/22/

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a try.

Comment: This only works on the landingpage (section with id main). How do I make it work on other sections?

Comment: @barney updated answer. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver! The first edit solution worked for me! Thanks!! +1